# Open network share windows file explorer equivalent

Tags: windows, nautilus, 22.04

In Windows I'm used to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or inside the file explorer <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to access the location bar and then just input the location on the disk when I want to open include a windows share:

i.e.:

`c:\windows`

`\\192.168.1.100\files`

etc.

Is it possible to do the same with Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do it with Ubuntu ?

You probably did not try. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in Files (nautilus) works the same.

You can set the shortcut key to launch the file manager to any you like in "Settings" - "Keyboard" - "Lanchers" - "Home folder". That will open the file manager, though you still need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to display the path bar.

If you prefer the location bar to always be there instead of the path buttons, there is a hidden setting that allows this (this used to be exposed in the preferences, but not anymore in Ubuntu 22.04):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true
```

When launching the file manager, the path bar will have initial keyboard focus.